# Mysql Query: returning rows where all preceding rows in group match a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Given a table like the following, which contains a list of names, tasks, priority of task, and status of task:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+------+--------+----------+--------+
| id | name | task   | priority | status |
+----+------+--------+----------+--------+
|  1 | bob  | start  |        1 | done   |
|  2 | bob  | work   |        2 | NULL   |
|  3 | bob  | finish |        3 | NULL   |
|  4 | jim  | start  |        1 | done   |
|  5 | jim  | work   |        2 | done   |
|  6 | jim  | finish |        3 | NULL   |
|  7 | mike | start  |        1 | done   |
|  8 | mike | work   |        2 | failed |
|  9 | mike | finish |        3 | NULL   |
| 10 | joan | start  |        1 | NULL   |
| 11 | joan | work   |        2 | NULL   |
| 12 | joan | finish |        3 | NULL   |
+----+------+--------+----------+--------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to build a query which returns only the next task to be run for each name. Specifically, I want to return the row containing the lowest number priority which has a NULL status per person.

But here's the catch: **I want to only return the row if all preceding tasks have a status of "done".**

Given the above table and query logic, the end result of this query should look like this:

```
+----+------+--------+----------+--------+
| id | name | task   | priority | status |
+----+------+--------+----------+--------+
|  2 | bob  | work   |        2 | NULL   |
|  6 | jim  | finish |        3 | NULL   |
+----+------+--------+----------+--------+
```

Initially, this was being done with a whole mess of sub-queries and derived tables, which extremely inefficient and slow. I have managed to speed it up considerably by using several temporary tables to get the result I want.

In the real world, this will be run on a table with about 200k records, and multiple servers will each be executing this query several times per minute. My current solution takes about 2 seconds to run, which simply won't do.

Here is the DML/DDL to get my example data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `task` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `test` VALUES 
(1,'bob','start',1,'done'),
(2,'bob','work',2,NULL),
(3,'bob','finish',3,NULL),
(4,'jim','start',1,'done'),
(5,'jim','work',2,'done'),
(6,'jim','finish',3,NULL),
(7,'mike','start',1,'done'),
(8,'mike','work',2,'failed'),
(9,'mike','finish',3,NULL),
(10,'joan','start',1,NULL),
(11,'joan','work',2,NULL),
(12,'joan','finish',3,NULL);
```

Here's what I am currently doing to get the desired result (which works, but is slow):

```
drop table if exists tmp1;
create temporary table tmp1 as 
select 
    name, 
    min(priority) as priority 
from test t 
where status is null 
group by name;
create index idx_pri on tmp1(priority);
create index idx_name on tmp1(name);

drop table if exists tmp2;
create temporary table tmp2 as 
select tmp.* 
from test t 
join tmp1 tmp 
    on t.name = tmp.name 
    and t.priority < tmp.priority 
group by name having sum(
    case when status = 'done' 
    then 0 
    else 1 
    end
) = 0;
create index idx_pri on tmp2(priority);
create index idx_name on tmp2(name);


select 
    t.*
from test t 
join tmp2 t2
    on t.name = t2.name
    and t.priority = t2.priority;
```

I have the DDL/DML in SQL Fiddle as well, but I can't put my solution in there because technically the creation of these temp tables is DDL, and it doen't allow DDL in the query box. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d9e2/1

Please help me with coming up with a better way to do this. I am open to modifying schema or  logic to accommodate outside of the box solutions as well, so long as said solution is efficient.

Comment: Just to be clear, why is Joan omitted?

Comment: I managed to remove derived tables from my query. Please time it when you get a chance :)

Comment: @Strawberry it's not really a requirement of the application that task #1 is specificallyincluded/excluded in the results of the query, so it doesn't matter either way, if there is a way to make a given query work better if it doesn't need to exclude task #1 (joan), then I would use that query, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn your logic pretty directly into a query like this:

```
select t.*
from test t 
where t.status is null and
      not exists (select 1
                  from test t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and
                        t2.id < t.id and
                        (t2.status <> 'done' or
                         t2.status is null
                        )
                 ) and
      exists (select 1
              from test t2
              where t2.name = t.name and
                    t2.id < t.id and
                    t2.status = 'done'
             );
```

For performance, create an index on `test(name, id, status)`.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d92c98/4) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, this does most of the work, however, it returns ALL of the tasks with NULL status instead of just the NEXT one. Which means I would still group it by the name and min(priority), then join that grouped result with the original table to get the results.

Comment: Ah, I see you've edited your answer right as I posted the above comment.. The new one ostensibly seems to work. I need to test it on the production system.

Comment: Initial testing looks quite good. Most queries are returning < 1sec. Up-voting your answer, but I'm going to hold off on accepting it for a day or two until I've thoroughly tested the solution as well as heard from anyone else on SO who might have an opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This query determines whether all tasks before a given task are done by verifying that the # of tasks that are not done before the given task are 0

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.id, t1.priority, t1.task
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 
    ON t2.name = t1.name
    AND t2.priority < t1.priority
WHERE t1.status IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.name, t1.priority, t1.id, t1.task
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.status = 'done' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) = 0 

CREATE INDEX test_index1 ON test (name,status,priority,id,task);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c912f/7

Comment: This solution is pretty elegant in it's simplicity. No subqueries, no derived tables. I will give this one a shot on the production system as well and let you know how it works out.

Comment: While this result does work pretty well, (5416 rows in set (2.62 sec)) it is still about a second slower than the accepted answer on a large table.

Answer (score 1):

I have no way of testing the speed against a really large table, but this at least returns the correct answer from your smaller sample table. It should be competitive with other answers, however, as it performs only one subquery without a join:

```
select  *
from    test  t1
where   t1.Status is null
  and exists (
    select 1
    from   test
    where  Name = t1.Name and
           Priority < t1.Priority
    group by Name
    having count(*) = sum( case when Status = 'done' then 1 else 0 end )
);
```

Comment: Hmm, this looks promising. Using a having sum(case) was something I was trying to go for originally, but could never quite get it to work right, this seems to be the correct version of what I was originally trying to do. I'll test it and let you know.

Comment: I love the simplicity, but for some reason that I can't explain, this solution takes an average of 9% more time to complete than the accepted answer. This is puzzling since the assumption would be that 1 correlated subquery would be faster than 2.

Comment: The next thing I would try is to create an index on (name, priority, status). But this is strictly an intuitive reaction. You should look at execution plans to get a better picture of how the query is being carried out and if there is a bottleneck somewhere that can be widened.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM test a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.name
            , MIN(x.priority) priority 
         FROM test x 
         LEFT 
         JOIN test y 
           ON y.name = x.name 
          AND y.priority < x.priority 
          AND y.status <> 'done' 
        WHERE y.id IS NULL 
          AND x.status IS NULL
        GROUP BY x.name
     ) b 
    ON b.name = a.name 
   AND b.priority = a.priority
   AND a.priority > 1;
```

Comment: Will joining a derived table be efficient here? As we all know, mysql doesn't index derived tables, and these queries are going to be run on tables with 200k+ records.

Comment: Why not suck it and see?

Comment: 5416 rows in set (3 min 8.76 sec).

Comment: Definitely not. As I said, joins against derived tables are optimized very poorly by MySQL and are (in my experience) almost never the right choice. This solution actually looks remarkably similar to what this application was using before I started attempting to optimize it.

Comment: Still, I'm surprised that this query takes so long. I assume you have a covering index on (name, priority) [or should that be (name, priority, status)?. It would be useful to see the EXPLAIN

Comment: Yes, I do have the indexes. The query inside the derived table only takes about a second to run, it's when that derived table (b) is joined against the main table (a) that the problem occurs. MySQL doesn't index the derived table (b), so it's doing a full table scan on that join. The derived table ends up being a few thousand records, so that's why its slow.

Comment: Just to test, I actually pulled the derived table query out and created a temp table and joined against that, and the whole thing only took a couple of seconds to run. So we're definitely dealing with the limitations of MySQL here. There's a few threads on SO dealing with the same problem. 
[Source1](http://tinyurl.com/m2367zo)
[Source2](http://tinyurl.com/mzwzdsf)